# > 'meteor run android' runs app and launches android emulator but I cannot find or run the application inside the emulator

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, android-emulator

To get started wtih android development, I am using the example application 'todos' from percolate studio
From Ubuntu 14.04 console running in VMWare Workstation 10, I can successfully run the todos application

```
gbdmeteor@ubuntu:~/todophone/todos$ meteor run android
Starting android emulator                                                  
[[[[[ ~/todophone/todos ]]]]]   

=> Started proxy.               
=> Started MongoDB.                                                        
=> Started Cordova (android).                                   
=> Started your app.                                                       

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

this launches android emulator but I cannot find/run the target application (todos) in the emulator.  What am I missing?

Comment: Meteor IRC comment:  build the app for the device .. you need to tell the meteor that build it for your android server
meteor build <buildfolder not under meteor project > -p http://meteor-server-url:port

Comment: ...But the command: meteor build <bundle path> --server <host>:<port> builds your app. seems to be for a device, not an emulator(?)

This will generate a directory at <target bundle path> which includes a server deployment tarball...

Comment: 'meteor run android --verbose'  indicates successful build and launch:  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 13 seconds
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: /home/gbdmeteor/todophone/todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/Todos-debug-unaligned.apk
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
Command finished with error code 0: /home/gbdmeteor/todophone/todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator

Comment: If you're running `meteor run android` inside a VM, I'm surprised it works. I tried this in VirtualBox (Ubuntu 14.04 guest, Windows host), and the Android SDK couldn't be installed in virtual machines.

Answer (score 4):

1. Using `http://localhost:3000` does not work because `localhost` only means something in the context of the host OS.
   Open Android's browser and go to my host computer's IP address:
   `192.168.56.130:3000` Then the meteor app comes up, just like in browser.
2. If I quit meteor app (ctl-c from commandline) and leave the android emulator running, 
   and then I 'meteor run android' from the commandline again...
   Meteor successfully loads, installs icon and launches the application!!

Now I must load the app to real android device and see if camera works.

Comment: The (2) still not works for me. I leaved emulator opened, and restarted app with "meteor run android" still no luck on it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$ export BIND_IP=[YOUR LOCAL IP, ie. 192.168.1.x]
$ meteor run android
```

If it's not already done, **do not forget to install the API 22** in Android Studio beforehand.